# Is Umbar a city or a region?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

On my middle earth map there is no Umbar, just the "city of the corsairs". Then when looking online I came across  a middle earth map that cited Umbar as a region rather than a city.

So my question is: is Umbar a city or a region?

Comment: I can be both (New York City and New York state).

Comment: Is this your map? http://corecanvas.s3.amazonaws.com/theonering-0188db0e/gallery/original/middle_earth_map.jpg - if so it's worth noting that this is the map drawn by Christopher Tolkien and published in earlier editions of Lord of the Rings, and has quite a few defects (noted by CT in his introduction to Unfinished Tales).

Answer (score 13):

It's both.

From the Lord of the Rings appendices, first we read:

> Umbar is made into a great fortress of Númenor.

And:

> King Eärnil I takes Umbar, which becomes a fortress of Gondor

And:

> King Ciryandil slain in the siege of Umbar.

These suggest that it is a walled fortress-city, which we know from elsewhere is also a port-city.

However, in a footnote to the appendices we also read:

> The great cape and land-locked firth of Umbar had been Númenorean land since days of old...

Which suggests that the name Umbar was also used of the region containing the city.

Comment: It's not exactly uncommon in out of universe history to name a region after its central city.

Comment: Also Bree-land and Bree for another in-universe example.

Comment: An entire region (if sufficiently defensible) can be (metaphorically) considered a "fortress".  For example, England was an "unsinkable aircraft carrier" during World War II.

Comment: @Jasper - it's difficult to besiege a region though.

Comment: The Germans tried to cut off England's supplies of food, weapons, and ammunition during World Wars I and II.  The United States successfully beseiged Japan during World War II.

Comment: @Jasper - and both were islands whereas Umbar was not.

Comment: An island is a peninsula with a moat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20855/discussion-between-darth-satan-and-jasper).